# SSRS - Could not generate chart in sub report

Tags: reporting-services, charts, subreport

I have a job to create sub report using chart by parsing parameter value from master report. I have checked there was no different data type and ensure that there is no null value. So at the first, I tried to make test case by creating sub report using standard table, and it works.

But, when I tried to use chart report in sub report with the same data and I run it from master report, **it didn't work** and the notice is

```
"Data retrieval failed for the subreport,'subrptqtybyasset', located at:/rptAssetQtyByType. Please check the log files for more information."
```

Then I try to look at sub report and running this chart alone and it works. Same result when I tried running sub report using standard table (not using chart).

So, my questions : **First**, why SSRS give different result when I execute sub report using chart, meanwhile it works by using table?. **Second**, is there any solution to make it work with chart on subreport?, because I really need using chart in my subreport.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the SSRS log file for a better description of what has errored. 
The default log file location in SQL Server 2008 is

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles

A similar path is used for other versions.

In the rare case that the SSRS log file doesn't reveal the cause of the error, you can run a SQL Profiler trace to the database specific in the report data source to try to work out what is going wrong when the report runs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Josh for the answer,
I have just run the program today and I see in the SSRS log file and there is no error statement,maybe you can see from this link : 
www.herryyulianto.com/images/stackoverflow/Response01.jpg

The error statement only appear in Visual Studio Reporting. Still same result as yesterday. 
Here are the last log that I got :

9/2/2014 9:46:11 AM spid56 Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'. 
9/2/2014 9:36:11 AM spid52 Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.

And this is master report that contains sub report chart when I execute : 
www.herryyulianto.com/images/stackoverflow/UsingChart.jpg

But if the master report contains sub report with standard table and I got : 
www.herryyulianto.com/images/stackoverflow/UsingStandardTable.jpg

Well, I don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks.